# C# Getting issues with the 7th line in my code

Tags: c#

I am reviewing issues with my code and its prompting this error message.

I have been working on the code for a bit and cant seem to figure out the issue

Error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   yValues'

Code:

```
int xValue = 0;
int yValue = 0;

System.Collections.IEnumerable YValues = null;
System.Collections.IEnumerable[] XValues = null;

Int32.TryParse(right1, out yValue);
Int32.TryParse(left1, out xValue); ;
Series Minimum = chart1.Series.Add("Minimum");
Minimum.Points.DataBindXY(YValues, XValues);
Minimum.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
Minimum.Color = Color.Red;
Minimum.BorderWidth = 3;
```

Comment: You shouldn't ignore return value of `TryParse` (rather use `Parse` then to have your softaware crashed), if it return `false` you don't have valid value to continue.

Comment: Error would be thrown in method `Minimum.Points.DataBindXY`, can you show this code. Actually don't - just set `YValues` to empty collection: `var YValues = Enumerable.Empty<int>()`

Comment: Ah yes i changed it to parse

Comment: Well atm i change to var YValues = Enumerable.Empty<int>() and im recieving errors with xValue and yValue

Comment: Seems like error lines have disappeared for the other values

Comment: The error its showing is that argument 2 may not passed with the 'out'  keyword

Comment: `int.Parse` and `int.TryParse` do not share the same signature, you should check it out. Your original problem, however, is the fact that you are passing `YValues` as `null` to `Minimum.Points.DataBindXY(YValues, XValues);` (as stated by Fabio)

Comment: Oh yes i see that now what i was trying to do was pass right1 and left1 to those values so i can use that data stored in those values in my graph

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is [`DataBindXY(IEnumerable`**`xValue`**`, IEnumerable[]`**`yValues`**`)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.databindxy?view=netframework-4.8).
Therefore, your initial error message is about the following line:

```
Minimum.Points.DataBindXY(YValues, XValues);
```

Because `XValues` (which is the `yValues` parameter of `DataBindXY`) is `null`, and shouldn't be.

See:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerable YValues = null;
System.Collections.IEnumerable[] XValues = null;
```

Comment: mmmh i see where you are coming from

Comment: Int32.Parse(right1, out YValues);
            Int32.Parse(left1, out XValues); does this peace of code put the right 1 value into the yvalues

Comment: This can't work, as neither `YValues` nor `XValues` are integers. Also this is not how `int.Parse` works

Comment: Main issue im getting is that Y values cannot be data bound to the string object.and just need to make this part work

Comment: main thing i need to do is figure out how to convert from 'int' to a 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: You don't convert from int to IEnumerable, you can create an empty enumerable (`Enumerable.Empty<int>()` as Fabio suggested) and insert an integer in it

Comment: Oh yeah its fine i figured out how to do it thanks for trying though i know im  a hard case